# Average Revenue Curve

Tags: microeconomics

[image]In the Average Revenue curve for a firm in perfect competition the average revenue is equal to the price of the commodity at all units of output sold.This is because the average revenue is equal to total revenue/output. When we are talking about perfect competition the price is always constant. So we can write revenue as price*output and the output cancels out. So the average revenue is equal to the price.Is this true at 0 units of output sold? How does it make sense that the average revenue exists at zero units of output sold. The reference is to the question asked above.[image]

Comment: "*It is said that...*" Please back up your claim with a reference!

Comment: @Giskard question edited

Comment: Okay. "*In the Average Revenue curve for a firm in perfect competition the average revenue is equal to the price of the commodity at all units of output sold.*" Please back up your claim with a reference!

Comment: @Giskard edited again

Comment: The problem with this question is that it takes this form: "*Clearly all floops all blarps. We know this because of foo fooo foooo. Why are all floops blarps?*" What exactly are you asking here? If your claim that you provide without a reference is true? If your "proof" is correct? If we can divide by zero?

Comment: @Giskard edited again with the reference to the question.

Comment: @Giskard What I was saying was how is revenue even obtained when the output is zero are we taking limits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142919/discussion-between-thecuriousone-and-giskard).

Comment: @Giskard please respond

Comment: Hi! I am not that interested, please stop tagging me. Someone else will probably come along. If not, consider improving your question to attract users & answers.

Comment: @TheCuriousOne people do not owe you answer please don't spam users by repeated requests, they will get notified about your first comment if they dont respond it is their prerogative

Comment: I thought the user would answer as he asked for an improvement in the question. But it was my mistake.